# Rake is trying to be too smart and discover endless loop before even triggering code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Today I was implepenting generator of random uniq strings for user (lets say something like a forgotten password token)

so I build up generator in *user_model*

```
  def generate_random_string
    random_string = CGI::escape( Base64.encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest("#{rand(1<<128)}/#{Time.now.to_f}/#{Process.pid}")))[0..12].downcase  #I was required it has to have max 12 chars
    if User.where( 'random_token_string = ?', random_string )
     #if the string exist generate new one
     self.generate_random_string 
    else
      self.random_token_string = random_string
    end

    return random_string
  end
```

works 100% in console in application for one or for several users

than I builded up a RAKE task too update existing users

```
task :generate_random_string_for_existing_users => :environment do
  User.all.each do |user|
    unless user.vanity_name
      user.generate_random_string
      p "#{user.id} failed to be updated for some reason !!!" unless user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

from my point of view everithing ok

but when I run that rake

```
RAILS_ENV=development  rake generate_random_string_for_existing_users  --trace
```

I'm getting

```
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
/home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:10
```

...nothing more nothing less. When I tried to run it from rails console it pass trought seccussfully

now when I coment out the recursion in the *user_model*

```
    #....
    if User.where( 'random_token_string = ?', random_string )
     #self.generate_random_string 
    else
    #....
```

...it will pass. So if I understand it correctly RAKE is trying to be smart even before the code is triggered. 
can anyone explain me why?

Comment: You should not use recursion for this in Ruby. Only use recursion for a loop in a language which has tail-call optimization, and only where the recursion is written such that the language can in fact transform the loop to a tail call.

Comment: so the moral of this story is : "don't use recursion (like this one) in ruby "    ....do I understand it correctly ?  ...rather do it with while like @Jesse Wolgamott  did it in the answer below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justice's comment is right on the money -- instead, just do something like:

```
def build_random_string
    CGI::escape( Base64.encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest("#{rand(1<<128)}/#{Time.now.to_f}/#{Process.pid}")))[0..12].downcase  #I was required it has to have max 12 chars
end

def random_string_is_unique?(random_string)
    User.where(:random_tokent_string => random_string).count == 0
end

def generate_random_string
  # we'll loop until we find a unique code
  # it will execute build_random_string once before checking the while condition
  begin
    self.random_token_string = build_random_string
  end while random_string_is_unique?(random_token_string)
end
```

Comment: this is nice one,  I refactored the code with while by myself but this is more elegant...